# Connect to the device which plug by usb debug, socket programing

Tags: android, sockets

I'm program a simple socket client-server application, the android device will be the server and the PC is the client.

At server side, open socket like this:

```
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
            Log.e("tag", getLocalIpAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            Message m = new Message();
            m.what = MSG_ID;
            try {
                if (s == null)
                    s = mServerSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                String st = null;
                st = input.readLine();
                mClientMsg = st;
                myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And the client side:

```
    Socket socket;
    try {
         InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
         socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 6000);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
         out.println("Hello server");
         System.out.println("Sent message to server");
      } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

After run the server, I've run the client, it's alway show

```
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.main(main.java:19)
```

Look like the ip address at the client side is not correct. But I don't what exactly the ip adress of server is!

Note: I use a real device, connect via USB debug.

Thank you.

Comment: What does USB have to do with sockets? Whatever that IP is, it doesn't exists / have a route to it.

Comment: Just like when use the Emulator, I can use with the 10.0.2.2, but on real device connect by usb, 10.0.2.2 doesn't work.

Comment: This project use a USB and the adb to use a socket
https://github.com/quamotion/madb

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the exact IP or an resolveable hostname of the device you with to connect to, you cannot use TCP directly.

You may think of doing broad- or multicast on the server-side to announce the server in the whole network or do a broad- or multicast to the server to discover its address; but that depends on the Application you're working on.

Comment: So I should use Emulator :-)